Why are some Chinese air to air missiles blue?

Why are some Chinese missiles blue? What purpose does this serve? I couldn’t seem to find any research on this.

Possibly those are inert "missiles". US Air Force and Navy do similar.
Here, an AIM-9 on F-16 wingtip launcher.

(pic from af.mil)

Ah okay, yeah that makes sense, thanks!

Confirmed.
